# display certain code based on variable passed in url using php

Tags: variables, wistia

Goal: display 1 of 4 Wistia videos based on url variable passed to php page.

Example url:

```
showvid.php?vid=1 or 
showvid.php?vid=2 or 
showvid.php?vid=3 or 
showvid.php?vid=4
```

In showvid.php:

some if/then statement where

```
if vid=1 then show wistia embed code 1
else
if vid=2 then show wistia embed code 2
else
if vid=3 then show wistia embed code 3
else
if vid=4 then show wistia embed code 4
```

Pretty straight forward. I apologize if this is answered elsewhere, I looked fairly extensively and couldn't find an answer that would work (plus I'm fairly new and my head is spinning after digging for a while).

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: pulled code from comment

URL: pagename.php?bucket=1

```
$bucket = $_GET["bucket"]
if ($bucket == 1) {
  $bucketdesc = 'Memory Vapor';
}
if ($bucket == 2) {
  $bucketdesc = 'Brain Trauma Syndrome';
}
else {
  goto "/pagetwo.php"
}
```

Comment: Do oyu have any code that you have tried already? If so please post it, along with any errors that may have cropped up during testing.

Comment: Sorry, I do not yet. I found a couple of examples that seem very complex for just a simple operation. Let me see what I can come up with. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, here is what I'm hoping to get done. Not sure it is the most elegant, or efficient but my little coding experience thinks it is close.

URL: pagename.php?bucket=1

'$bucket = $_GET["bucket"] '

'if ($bucket == 1){ $bucketdesc = 'Memory Vapor';}
if ($bucket == 2){ $bucketdesc = 'Brain Trauma Syndrome';}
else
{
    goto "/pagetwo.php"
}'

Comment: Did you try the code you mention? Also, when you add code like that, please add it to the body of your post using the edit function instead of dropping it in a comment, it makes it mcuh easier to read - especially if you put it in a code block. This looks like a perfect candidate for a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement.

Comment: Moved the code from your comment into your post. One thing that jumps out to start is your second if else statement.  The first `if` isn't a part of the second statement, so even if `$bucket == 1` it will still `goto "/pagetwo.php"`.  You need to change the second if to `else if ($bucket == 2) {`

Comment: Hey Wolffer-east, first off, thank you for cleaning up my question. I thought I had done it properly, but obviously not.

I got it to work. Ill post answer below. 

Without your help, I wouldn't have gotten it. Yahoo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The resulting code that worked was...

```
if ($bucket == 1) {
$bucketdesc = 'desc1';
$bucketvid = 'embed code';}
elseif ($bucket == 2) {
$bucketdesc = 'desc2';
$bucketvid = 'embed code2';}
elseif ($bucket == 3) {
$bucketdesc = 'desc3';
$bucketvid = 'embed code3';}
elseif ($bucket == 4) {
$bucketdesc = 'desc4';
$bucketvid = 'embed code4';}
```

I had forgotten the ; at then end of each statement! doh...